# pandas dataframe view vs copy, how do I tell?

Tags: python, pandas

What's the difference between:

pandas `df.loc[:,('col_a','col_b')]`

and

`df.loc[:,['col_a','col_b']]`

The link below doesn't mention the latter, though it works. Do both pull a view? Does the first pull a view and the second pull a copy?

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: both are the same and will return a view

Comment: and how can you tell, other than being a pandas jedi

Comment: The docs state this is so, plus if you try something like `df[:][['a','b']] = 5` it'll raise a warning

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If your DataFrame has a simple column index, then there is no difference.
For example,

```
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), columns=list('ABC'))

In [9]: df.loc[:, ['A','B']]
Out[9]: 
   A   B
0  0   1
1  3   4
2  6   7
3  9  10

In [10]: df.loc[:, ('A','B')]
Out[10]: 
   A   B
0  0   1
1  3   4
2  6   7
3  9  10
```

But if the DataFrame has a MultiIndex, there can be a big difference:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,4)),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['foo']*2+['bar']*2,
                                                     list('ABAB')]),
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['baz']*2+['qux']*3,
                                                   list('CDCDC')]))

#       foo    bar   
#         A  B   A  B
# baz C   7  9   9  9
#     D   7  5   5  4
# qux C   5  0   5  1
#     D   1  7   7  4
#     C   6  4   3  5

In [27]: df.loc[:, ('foo','B')]
Out[27]: 
baz  C    9
     D    5
qux  C    0
     D    7
     C    4
Name: (foo, B), dtype: int64

In [28]: df.loc[:, ['foo','B']]
KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (1), lexsort depth (0)'
```

The KeyError is saying that the MultiIndex has to be lexsorted. If we do that, then we still get a different result:

```
In [29]: df.sortlevel(axis=1).loc[:, ('foo','B')]
Out[29]: 
baz  C    9
     D    5
qux  C    0
     D    7
     C    4
Name: (foo, B), dtype: int64

In [30]: df.sortlevel(axis=1).loc[:, ['foo','B']]
Out[30]: 
      foo   
        A  B
baz C   7  9
    D   7  5
qux C   5  0
    D   1  7
    C   6  4
```

Why is that? `df.sortlevel(axis=1).loc[:, ('foo','B')]` is selecting the column where the first column level equals `foo`, and the second column level is `B`.

In contrast, `df.sortlevel(axis=1).loc[:, ['foo','B']]` is selecting the columns where the first column level is either `foo` or `B`. With respect to the first column level, there are no `B` columns, but there are two `foo` columns.

I think the operating principle with Pandas is that if you use `df.loc[...]` as
an *expression*, you should assume `df.loc` may be returning a copy or a view. The Pandas docs do not specify any rules about which you should expect.
However, if you make an *assignment* of the form

```
df.loc[...] = value
```

then you can trust Pandas to alter `df` itself.

The reason why the documentation warns about the distinction between views and copies is so that you are aware of the pitfall of using chain assignments of the form

```
df.loc[...][...] = value
```

Here, Pandas evaluates `df.loc[...]` first, which may be a view or a copy. Now if it is a copy, then

```
df.loc[...][...] = value
```

is altering a copy of some portion of `df`, and thus has no effect on `df` itself. To add insult to injury, the effect on the copy is lost as well since there are no references to the copy and thus there is no way to access the copy after the assignment statement completes, and (at least in CPython) it is therefore soon-to-be garbage collected.

---

I do not know of a practical fool-proof *a priori* way to determine if `df.loc[...]` is going to return a view or a copy.

However, there are some rules of thumb which may help guide your intuition (but note that we are talking about implementation details here, so there is no guarantee that Pandas needs to behave this way in the future):

- If the resultant NDFrame can not be expressed as a basic slice of the
  underlying NumPy array, then it probably will be a copy. Thus, a selection of arbitrary rows or columns will lead to a copy. A selection of sequential rows and/or sequential columns (which may be expressed as a slice) may return a view.
- If the resultant NDFrame has columns of different dtypes, then `df.loc`
  will again probably return a copy.

However, there is an easy way to determine if `x = df.loc[..]` is a view *a postiori*: Simply see if changing a value in `x` affects `df`. If it does, it is a view, if not, `x` is a copy.

Comment: If we are simply using an expression like `df.loc[..]` and it turns out to be a copy, then why would something like `df.loc[..] = ...` somehow become a view? Seems fishy. But thank you so much for your explanation. It is feeling quite clearer now.

Comment: When used as an expression, `df.loc[...]` is calling `df.loc.__getitem__(...)`. When uses as an assignment, `df.loc[...] = value` is calling `df.loc.__setitem__(..., value)`. The `__getitem__` method may return a view or a copy. But the `__setitem__` method will always modify `df` itself. After all, that's the only reasonable thing for a `__setitem__` to do.

Comment: @user3659451 don't be concerned about whether something is a view. There are only certain circumstances when it *can* be a view, but NONE are guaranteed. Just use ``.loc`` to set and you will be fine. Views are a function of the memory layout of the underlying data and how it is selected.

Comment: Thanks you too. This makes sense. I think I was concerned about stuff for memory purposes.  I'm dealing with over 2MM records, ~40 columns. Sometimes things are just weird. Datatypes change depending on how I go about things (eg. if apple is an `int64` column, `df.loc[:,'apple']` becomes a `float64` column and it sucks because then I have to `astype` it back into a `int64`. I guess I have to deal with that, or just call/set `df.loc[:,['apple']]`, I'm getting it little by little.

Comment: @user3659451: That seems surprising to me, and is perhaps a bug. If you can produce an example demonstrating the `int64` to `float64` behavior, that would be a worthy SO question, or even raising as [an issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues).

Comment: it seems it is difficult to reproduce :( in general. But on my dataframe it can be reproduced, though I can't share it as it's company property. Thanks for showing me where to post bugs though.