# Set values after multiple selections on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

I have a (possibly large) `DataFrame` and I want to set values based on multiple criteria.

I would like to do this by first applying the "big cut" once, and then changing values on parts of that slice. But I want these changes to apply to the original `DataFrame`, so I don't want a copy when I do the first selection.

Here is a simple example.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame( [(1,2,3),
                        (4,5,6),
                        (7,8,9)],
                       columns=["x","y","z"]
                       )

# the "big cut" -- does this return a copy? why?
vw = df.loc[ df["x"]<5, : ]

# the "sub" selections set values only in vw, not df
vw.loc[ vw["z"]>5, "z" ] = 666
vw.loc[ vw["y"]<5, "y" ] = 222

print "vw:"
print vw
print "df:"
print df
```

which prints the result:

```
vw:
   x    y    z
0  1  222    3
1  4    5  666

df:
   x  y  z
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

My **desired** result:

```
df_ideal:
   x    y    z
0  1  222    3
1  4    5  666
2  7    8    9
```

How can I do my sub-selections on a view rather than a copy? I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296282/what-rules-does-pandas-use-to-generate-a-view-vs-a-copy), but it seems like I should be getting a view by those rules. (I am using Pandas 0.19.2 and Python 2.7.10)

Comment: It returns a copy (execute `df.loc[df["x"]<5, :]._is_view` or `bool(df.loc[df["x"]<5, :].is_copy)`. As far as I know, there is no way to operate on a view with boolean indexing. You'll have to do `cond1 = df["x"]<5`  and then `df.loc[cond1 & (df['z'] > 5)] = 666`.

Comment: So .. could I use the `Series` of booleans to get a `Series` of index values (of `df`) and then use index slicing with that to keep only views? But then I'm also confused -- if boolean indexing returns a copy, why do the values in `vw` get set correctly?

Comment: It surely modifies the DataFrame it was called on if you use it for setting (i.e. you can be sure that `df.loc[something] = 5`  will modify the original DataFrame. However, `another_df = df.loc[something]` may or may not return a view (a simple column selection returns a view for example). The changes you do in `another_df`  then, may or may not be reflected in the original df.

Comment: See [@unutbu's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367442/pandas-dataframe-view-vs-copy-how-do-i-tell#comment43188590_27367693) on why the first one doesn't work but the second one works.

Comment: How about index on the subset, but still set on the original `df.ix[vw[vw["z"]>5].index, "z"] = 666`. I think `ix` operation is fast.